# Flask application not deploying to Heroku (Problem with "ikp3db"?)

Tags: python, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I was trying to deploy my app to Heroku the other day and I came across this error:

> Collecting ikp3db==1.4
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ikp3db==1.4

What does `ikp3db==1.4` mean? I tried removing it from my `requirements.txt` file and successfully pushed, although the default page ended up loading very slowly.

How do I fix this so that I can properly deploy my application?

For context, I am trying to push a Flask Application with Socket.io in it.

Here is the relevant part of the deploy log:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting ikp3db==1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_6a70450c1a3e03480c6a367846a7a630/requirements.txt (line 37))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ikp3db==1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_6a70450c1a3e03480c6a367846a7a630/requirements.txt (line 37)) (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4)
remote:        No matching distribution found for ikp3db==1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_6a70450c1a3e03480c6a367846a7a630/requirements.txt (line 37))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [its PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/ikp3db/):

> IKP3db is a Python 3 debugger.

Generally speaking, debuggers shouldn't be deployed to production servers. They represent a significant security risk.

> I tried removing it from my `requirements.txt` file and successfully pushed, although the default page ended up loading very slowly.

Removing a debugger wouldn't cause your application to be slow. There's something else going on. Start by looking at your browser's devtools to see if you can determine which part of the application is slow. Depending on what information you log, the [`heroku logs` command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs) may also be helpful here.

Comment: Turns out my mistake was really simple. I forgot to install the Node.js package and create a package.json file my root directory, so my javaScript wasn't working. Thanks, though!